# Notification bar doesn't disappear on clicking the question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications, notification-bar

Whenever I earn a new badge a notification bar is displayed, which says something like "You earned a *badge* for *question/answer*. See your *profile*". But on clicking the question/answer link to navigate to it on the new page it is displayed again. I have to click on the profile link to make it disappear. I believe this is a minor bug.

Answer (score 8):

As Jeff "said" through editing your question, that's kind of meant to be like that [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

While I do agree it's a minor annoyance, it can also be seing as a nice "*be sure to check your new badge, dude!*" kind of message, which is kind of cool. Maybe that's what he meant.