# Multi tab notifications

Tags: feature-request, support, notifications

I was just wondering if there was any way not to get notifications on all open Stack Overflow tabs (such as an answer to a question, or acquiring a new badge). At least, could they be suppressed when I see the answer or acknowledge that I got the badge, and not have to do it on all the tabs.

And if this doesn't exist, could it be implemented ?

I'm often "tricked" into looking one of my questions ten times in a row.

Comment: Does your browser not have a "Refresh" button?

Comment: Oh wow, I don't know if I was born an idiot, but I certainly do look like one now 

edit - and sorry for the annoyance

Answer (score 1):

I support this desire to improve the notification bar.

My suggestion would be to only show the notification bar ONCE.  So, when I click on a link in the bar *I don't have to see that same notification again in the new window*.

Comment: This persistent behavior [appears to be by-design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58473/notification-bar-doesnt-disappear-on-clicking-the-question).

Comment: @CodyGray: The design makes me unhappy.  Like a great dane forced to wear a cardigan and appear on a youtube video, to be laughed at by tens of thousands.  A once noble creature, reduced to a laughingstock.  Or something.