# Orange notification bar on top does not disappear if clicking on the profile link

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-overflow, notification-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notification bar doesn't disappear on clicking the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58473/notification-bar-doesnt-disappear-on-clicking-the-question)

The scenario was as follow:

I had **4 tabs** on Firefox 12.0 under Ubuntu 12.04 **opened** on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Mean while, an orange bar appears stating that I've earned a new badge.

I clicked the profile link that opened a new browser tab with my user profile!

After viewing it, I closed the tab and returned to the previous one, but the orange bar was still there! I've click on the link again and again... The orange bar was persistent, so I pressed the `X` to close it.

## The question is:

Shouldn't the orange bar get closed if I follow the profile link?
*Since I've already noticed it and take some action in regards to its contents!*

#### Additionally,

I was only expecting it to close on the tab where I follow the profile link from!
But since it pop'd out on all 4 tabs, should disappear on all 4 as well, for consistency sake.

---

**Notes:**

On [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58473/notification-bar-doesnt-disappear-on-clicking-the-question), the OP stated that by clicking the profile link, the orange notification bar got closed!
Quotation: *"I have to click on the profile link to make it disappear."*

Comment: I saw that, but quoting from [Notification Bar doesn't...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58473/notification-bar-doesnt-disappear-on-clicking-the-question):  _"I have to click on the profile link to make it disappear"_ and that's **exactly what I did** and the Orange bar didn't disappear!

Comment: Oh, yeah it appears your problem is that it was open on each of the 4 tabs, and it doesn't close on all 4 tabs when you close it on one of them. You have to refresh the page, then it'll be gone.

Comment: Actually I was only expecting it to close on the tab where I follow the link! But since it pop'd out on all 4 tabs, should disappear on all 4 as well, for consistency sake.

Comment: I'm no guru, but it seems like this is a lot of work (configuring the system to push notifications about whether or not a notification has been dismissed) for no real gain (helping you remember that... you _just_ clicked on the banner manually, apparently?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have to be frank here: No, we won't be doing this.

You're talking about a complex inter-tab push system (which we have for other uses, but that's besides the point) to alert every page you have open to dismiss a banner that will go away itself on the next page load because *you* chose to open it in a new tab (not something the link would do itself).

This is *definitely* not a bug.  Related: there are other, larger, changes in the pipe to those banners...time spent on anything like this would be wasted dev effort.

Comment: Tks! I just needed some clarification to why did it happen!

Comment: +1 for "there are other, larger, changes in the pipe to those banners".