# Comment delete control unusably small on mobile site. Can it be made larger?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, design, mobile-web

The tiny little x box at the end of a comment used to delete that comment on my phone is extremely hard to press. Have not been able to as I am restricted to only my small smartphone screen and big farm boy fingers. Would there be any chance of like at the end of a question using a text link to effect the deletion?

Comment: Sorry I again did not clarify I have theluttle x box it is three but I can not physically press the x even if I zoom all the way in my finger is to wide or whatnot then maybe increase the size of the x box relative to the small tesxt

Comment: OK. I edited the title and will migrate it.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100706/how-do-i-delete-or-flag-comments-using-the-mobile-website

Comment: Agreed as I can easily minipulate the text links already in use this would make the most sense to me personalty. Of course makeing it bigger well how much biggerand all that jazz. So a text link would be less objective as to a "good" size.

Comment: Also, the dropdown notification also uses an x box as I have to go view my profile to click these can these also be changed to fit the other standard of text based button interactions. The x looks cool but is functionally difficult to use.

Comment: It takes about 10 clicks to vote on a comment, let alone try to delete my own!

Comment: Possible fix without changing drop down notifications. Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58473/notification-bar-doesnt-disappear-on-clicking-the-question

Comment: Does your smartphone allow you to zoom in on the area to make the target bigger? I always end up having to do that on the IPad when voting on comments.

Comment: Yes,  fully zoom in and the x-box is still too small full-site and mobile versions.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I have also tried useing different browsers and magnifying applications

Comment: I appreciate your comments and suggestions. Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

As a work-around, the mobile theme now has "delete" links on comments.

Comment: Testing this feature... It works, but its somewhat ugly. Oh well, nothings perfect!

Comment: excellent new feature will allow me to better participate in the site.